# mapproxy+nginx+uwsgi

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Подскажите, как завести данную связку: `nginx+uwsgi+mapproxy`.
Когда она в виде `apache+mod_wsgi+mapproxy`, то всё работает, всё как по докам.
А с `nginx+uwsgi`, что-то не получается. Точнее, не работает через `unix socket`. При использовании протокола `http` снова всё работает.

И не работает при любых раскладах: запускаю `uwsgi` как приложение, или помещаю его в `systemd`. При этом, приложение из документации к uwsgi работает.

Нерабочесть выглядит так, что невозможно доступиться до адреса тайлового сервиса. Если стартануть `mapproxy-util serve-develop approxy.yaml`, то снова работет и есть доступ до demo странички.

Вот конфиг `uwsgi`

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
virtualenv = /var/www/vwrapper
home = /var/www/vwrapper
chdir = /var/www/vwrapper/mapproxy
wsgi-file = /var/www/vwrapper/mapproxy/mapproxy.py
socket = /var/www/vwrapper/mapproxy/mapproxy.sock
processes = 5
threads = 5
wsgi-disable-file-wrapper=false
logto = /var/log/mapproxy.log
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
buffer-size = 32768
```

Настройка `nginx`:

```
upstream mapproxy {
    server unix:/var/www/vwrapper/mapproxy/mapproxy.sock;
}
...
location /mapproxy {
include uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_pass mapproxy;
}
```

Приложение

```
# WSGI module for use with Apache mod_wsgi or gunicorn
# # uncomment the following lines for logging
# # create a log.ini with `mapproxy-util create -t log-ini`
from logging.config import fileConfig
import os.path

def application(env, start_response):
    fileConfig(r'/var/www/vwrapper/mapproxy/log.ini', {'here': os.path.dirname(__file__)})
    from mapproxy.wsgiapp import make_wsgi_app
    application = make_wsgi_app(r'/var/www/vwrapper/mapproxy/mapproxy.yaml', reloader=True)
```

Файл maxproxy.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Bingo uwsgi apps
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'cd /var/www/vwrapper/mapproxy; source /var/www/vwrapper/bin/activate; uwsgi --ini /var/www/vwrapper/mapproxy/mapproxy.ini'
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Единственное, что в логах появляется по этой теме:

```
*1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: client_ip, server: localhost, request: "GET /mapproxy HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/www/vwrapper/mapproxy/mapproxy.sock:", host: "***.***.***.***"
```

Comment: Приложение кажется на питоне, а путь к питону?

Comment: Я указал в конфиге так virtualenv = /var/www/vwrapper
Тестовое приложение, из документации, отлично отрабатывает.